# Video capture and stream in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-streaming, libvlc

I'm working on a problem, where as the input it takes video data(raw data) from a server(Network Video Recorder) and just streams the video using VLC. The data is provided in the pointer form (provided in code part) and I want to be able to capture and stream the video.

I have already tried to use OpenCV and VLC to capture data, but I don't have experience with video in C++ and I wasn't able to get those data. In OpenCV, I passed the server ip and login info like ("http://username:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/yuv/video.yuv") into VideoCapture() as an argument but it didn't work.

The code where the video data is from the NVR Sdk, where the video is passed frame by frame as the pointer.

...

```
typedef struct FrameHeadr 
{ 
  unsigned char mediaType;  
  unsigned char * pData;    //video Data as a pointer    
  unsigned int preBufSize;           
  unsigned int dataSize;             
  unsigned char frameRate;          
  unsigned int frameID;             
  unsigned int timeStamp;            
  union 
  { 
    struct { 
      int keyFrame;                 
      unsigned short videoWidth;    
      unsigned short videoHeight;   
    } videoParam; 
        unsigned char audioMode;         
  }; 
} FrameHeadr; 
typedef FrameHeadr * pFrameHeadr;
```

...

When the video data is captured or save, it doesn't need to be trans coded, just to be able to get the data and stream as RTSP in VLC. Since I'm a new learner, any suggestion, link or methodology how to do it, is appreciated. If the way how I am trying to capture video is wrong, pleas can you suggest any other method?

Comment: _"I passed the server ip and login info into VideoCapture() as an argument but it didn't work."_ It didn't work is a quite vague problem description. Elaborate about what exactly _didn't work_ please.

Comment: What do yo me at by “capture” if it’s in memory, it’s already captured. Also the URL implies raw YUV. Where does h.264 come into the picture? Where is the encoding taking place?

Comment: change http to rtsp